# what the name of service in ClientLogin for Android cloud to device?

Tags: java, android

i wonder what is the name of the service in ClientLogin for Android cloud to device, i found [this link](http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/faq.html#clientlogin) for all the service but i didnt find C2DM in it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The service is `ac2dm`. [Here is a sample authentication shell script](http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/blob/master/Push/C2DM/auth.sh).

Answer (score 0):

The service is "ac2dm", means Android C2DM. You can use "curl" command to get ClientLogin token. Or fire a http post with program language like Java. 
You may want to check this post [C2DM: Get ClientLogin Authentication Token](http://situee.blogspot.com/2011/08/c2dm-get-clientlogin-authentication.html)